# Different timestamp when querying with node-postgres and raw sql

Tags: node.js, postgresql, docker, prisma, sql-timestamp

My postgres database is running in docker. I started nestjs server from host terminal. The database is created in another microservice
with prisma.

My time zone is UTC+5. I am running query below with node-postgres:

```sql
INSERT INTO "Chat" default values RETURNING *
```

The inserted data is saved -10h instead of -5h.

Table definition:

```sql
CREATE TABLE "Chat" (
    "id" UUID NOT NULL DEFAULT gen_random_uuid(),
    "created_at" TIMESTAMP(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

    CONSTRAINT "Chat_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
```

What I am expecting is node-postgres should insert row with MY_TIME_ZONE - 5h, not MY_TIME_ZONE - 10h.

MOREOVER:

```sql
select current_timestamp; 
-- this returns:  2023-11-12 15:18:37.322506+00
-- while my time: 2023-11-12 20:18:37.322506+00
```

Comment: why now() is different in insert and select?

Comment: What is the reason why you expect `now()` to return the same values in both successive queries?

Comment: @Atmo because when selecting the inserted row later, the created_at is -5 hours than my expected

Comment: I see... basically, the latter half of your question is useless, what you are truly asking is what you show right before "*What I am expecting is node-postgres should return exact same timestamp.*". `2023-11-12T02:55:51.480Z` may actually be the same as `2023-11-12 07:55:51.480`. Do you know what the `Z` mean in the former? Is your computer running on UTC+05:00 (or possibly although less likely UTC-05:00), perhaps?

Comment: @Atmo I updated the question. The inserted data is actually twice behind my timezone. Select query working correctly.

Comment: How is the data inserted ? Maybe you have something that is incorrectly "correcting" the timezone

Comment: 1) What does `show timezone;`  return from the database? 2) This `TIMESTAMP(3)` is not a good idea, it should be `TIMESTAMPTZ(3)`. 3) I'm guessing the combination of 1) and 2) is rotating the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually set up the timezone you're currently based on, in both postgresql as well as docker to synchronize it -

```sql
SET timezone='UTC+5';
```

for postgresql, and for docker you can check the current time zone setting in your Docker container by executing -

```bash
docker exec -it <container_name_or_id> date
```

If the time zone is incorrect, you may need to adjust it in your Dockerfile or docker-compose.yml. For example, you can set the environment variable TZ -

```bash
environment:
  - TZ=Asia/Kolkata
```

and, for the node.js application to know what's going on, use the `process.env.TZ` variable at the beginning of your script.

```js
process.env.TZ = 'UTC+5';
```

having them all syncronized together shouldn't allow any room for errors.